# Appending 2 panda tables with same columns creates another column?

Tags: python, pandas, recursion

I am trying to append to Panda tables, but when doing so, a both a new column and some rows are created created somehow.
I do not get where it comes from. I used both the `concat` and `append` function and i saw the examples in other posts but somehow for me it does not work.
This is what happens:

let us say as ab example i have `df1`:

```
"x" "y" "id"
 1   2   1
 1   3   1
 ...
```

and `df2`:

```
"x" "y" "id"
 5   6   2
 4   7   2
 ...
```

I want a table like:

```
"x" "y" "id"
 1   2   1
 1   3   1
 ...
 5   6   2
 4   7   2
 ...
```

When i use:

```
df=df.append(df2)
```

somehow i get this:

```
0   "x" "y" "id"
"x"  NaN  NaN NaN
"y"  NaN  NaN NaN
"id" NaN  NaN NaN
NaN   1    2   1
NaN   1    3   1
     ...
NaN   5    6   2
NaN   4    7   2
   ...
```

Does anyone have an idea why?
My code looks like this:

```
columns = ["x", "y", "t", "id", "id2"]
df_allTrajectories=pd.DataFrame(columns)
for z in range(trajectory_amount):
    ....does sth
    f = open("...")
    with open("...") as f1:
        data3 = f1.read()
        TESTDATA = StringIO(data3)
    df = pd.read_table(TESTDATA, sep=" ")
    df.columns = ["x", "y", "id", "id2"]
    df.insert(loc=2, column='t', value=0)
    df.loc[:, 't'] = 0
    df.loc[:, 'id2'] = 0
    df.loc[:, 'id'] = z
    df.columns = ["x", "y", "t", "id", "id2"]
    df['id2'] =1
    df['id2'] = df.groupby('id')['id2'].cumsum().add(-1)
    df['t'] =1
    df['t'] = df.groupby('id')['t'].cumsum().add(-1)
    df_allTrajectories = df_allTrajectories.append(df)
```

So i am recursively appending `df` `z` times to `df_allTrajectories`. They both have 5 columns but somehow i get a similar wrong output like in the example above. Does anyone know why?

I also tried deleting this new first column by

```
df_allTrajectories.drop(df_allTrajectories.columns[[0]], axis=1)
```

but without any effect.

Comment: pd.concat([df1,df2])

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html

Comment: I tried concat but it happens just the same as with append

Comment: @FHTMitchell that is not a duplicate, concat is not working as i want it to work. i know what concat does but it seems to be a problem with my data

Comment: It worked fine for me with the data you provided. What error do you get? We won't debug for you.

Comment: I know that you won't debug. I do not get an error but I get an output that is quite different from how it looks when i see other examples of the `append` or `concat` functions. You can see my example above. I do not get why I get that 3 upper rows and the first column, like i explain in my example. Do you have any idea?